# How to upload images at three imageViewer on one Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

I have three imageViews on my Activity. In each ImageView I want to upload another picture. If the user click on the icon (image1/image2/image3) the galery opens so the user can choose a pic to upload it on the imageView. At my code, i have only one imageView works.

So my question. How can i modify the onActivityResult Method to check which imageView is clickt, and call the setImageBitmapMethod on it?

Here is my code

```
image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_three_1);
    image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_three_2);
    image3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_three_3);

    image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }
    });

    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        image1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

}
```

Comment: take different request code.

Comment: thank you, can you give me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip payal tuteja. I made three different Result Variables (RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 / RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 / RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE3 ) and then i set the right imageView on the right RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 Variable.

Here the code that works for me

```
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 = 2;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE3 = 3;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_for_three);

    //load titles from string.xml
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    //load icons from string.xml
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);

    image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_three_1);
    image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_three_2);
    image3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_three_3);

    image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);


        }
    });

    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2);
        }
    });

    image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE3);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        image1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        image2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        image3.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

}
```